# StencilJS event when child component is updated

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

If I had something like this in StencilJS.

```
<mycomponent>
   <my-other-compoent></my-other-compoennt>
</mycomponent>
```

Would I be able to notify `<mycompoent>` when any child component is updated?

Comment: What do you mean by "updated"? As in, the `componentDidUpdate()` hook was called? https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle#componentdidupdate-

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@Event` to notify your `<mycompoent>` that something is changed in child component.

For e.g. in your child component create an event like

```
@Event({ bubbles: true, composed: true }) dataChanged: EventEmitter<boolean>;
```

and emit this event when something is changed in child component

```
this.dataChanged.emit(true);
```

Now in your parent component Listen the event which is emitted by your child
For e.g. in your parent component handle the Listenevnt

```
@Listen('dataChanged',{target: "body"})
    getChangedValue(event: CustomEvent) {
        if (event.detail) {
            let data = event.detail;
            // do something with your data
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just adding that this works well with components, and the answer is correct. However, when dealing with classes exported from a .ts file this won't work. I use npm package stongly-typed-events in these cases.

Comment: hi @BrunoPolo so what's your solution for that??

Comment: @Franva nowadays I use two strategies: first the child component accepts a prop that is function type (onUpdated, for example). Then just calling it from inside the child component runs the function from parent component. The second strategy is to use rxjs to spread global messages.

Comment: thanks @BrunoPolo, these two options sound like the ways I do in Reactjs. I also found that by using the `@Event` and `@Listen`, I am able to do the same.